# Asignar valor a una lista en C# de forma dinamica

Tags: c#, lista

Buen día estoy realizando en C# una lista en la cual quiero que mediante un `Array()` se genere otra lista con los atributos del `Array()` usando un `for`
 esto es lo que llevo pero no se como puedo asignar valores a la propiedad dinámica que se acaba de crear.

```
string[] propiedades = { "foo","x"};
var prueba = new List<string>();
for(int x = 0;x <= propiedades;x++){
    prueba.Add(propiedades[x]);
    prueba.propiedades[x]="test";
}
```

busco que quede algo asi:

```
prueba.foo: "test"
prueba.x:"x"
```

No se si esto que quiero hacer sea posible
muchas gracias de antemano

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Quieres que en la lista se almacene la cadena `prueba.foo: "test"`? La verdad no entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Creo que tienes mal entendido el concepto del List<string>, quieres crear una propiedad según lo que tu traes del Array y despues acceder mediante el List a esa propiedad durante o fuera del ciclo for. Deberias crear una Clase con las propiedades que necesitas e instanciar tu List<MiClase> prueba = new List<MiClase>(); 
Luego si esto fuera posible, como harías para acceder a esta variable si no sabes como se llama?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es directamente posible, pero lo más cercano es un [*diccionario*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-MX/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.5):

```
Dictionary<string, string> prueba = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int x = 0; x < propiedades.Length; x++)
{
    prueba.Add(propiedades[x], "valor123");
}
```

Así puedes consumirlo:

```
Console.WriteLine(prueba["foo"]); // valor123
```

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias evaluar usar los `tipos dinamicos` de c#

[Uso de tipo dinámico (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

[Tutorial: Crear y usar objetos dinámicos (C# y Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects)

puede no ser simples de entender al principio, pero creo que resuelve el caso que planteas
Aunque hay que tener en cuenta que no tendras intellisense en el codigo con las propiedades dinamicas

Particularmente recomiendo analices la clase

[DynamicObject Clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.8)

con este podras crear la clase que buscas como se explica aqui

[Dynamically Add C# Properties at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819720/dynamically-add-c-sharp-properties-at-runtime)

observa como define la clase

```
public sealed class MyDynObject : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _properties;

    public MyDynObject(Dictionary<string, object> properties)
    {
        _properties = properties;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return _properties.Keys;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (_properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = _properties[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (_properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            _properties[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Para usarla

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"prop1", 12}
}

dynamic dyn = new MyDynObject(properties);
Console.WriteLine(dyn.prop1);
```

despues de cargar el diccionario de propiedades y valores puedes acceder a estos directo como si la key fuera una propiedad

Answer (score 0):

No lo puedes hacer porque no has entendido string, string es una cadena de caracteres, puedes tener un array de cadenas de caracteres o incluso una lista de cadenas, o una lista de arrays de cadenas, etc..., pero sospecho que no es lo que quieres

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es tener una clase dinámica a la cual añadas propiedades o atributos, si es eso, mira este enlace, aquí tienes la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067241/add-properties-dynamically-at-run-time-in-existing-class-c-sharp